# Java HashSet (Long vs Integer)

Tags: java, long-integer, hashset

I was solving this problem, (41 from Project Euler), where I noticed that contains method of HashSet is working differently for Long as compared to Integer (I might be wrong here, please correct me if I am).

The question is -

> We shall say that an n-digit number is pandigital if it makes use of
>   all the digits 1 to n exactly once. For example, 2143 is a 4-digit
>   pandigital and is also prime.
>
> What is the largest n-digit pandigital prime that exists?

My code for checking whether the number is Pandigital or not is -

```
private static boolean isPan(Long n) {
        HashSet<Long> list = new HashSet<Long>();
        int count = 0;
        while(n != 0){
            list.add(n%10);
            count++;
            n /= 10;
        }
        for(int i = 9; i>count; i--){
            if(list.contains(i)) return false;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i<= count; i++){
            if(!list.contains(i)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This code gave me an infinite loop. So, I changed my code like this -

```
private static boolean isPan(Long n) {
        HashSet<Integer> list = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int count = 0;
        while(n != 0){
            list.add((int) (n%10));
            count++;
            n /= 10;
        }
        for(int i = 9; i>count; i--){
            if(list.contains(i)) return false;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i<= count; i++){
            if(!list.contains(i)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I just changed, `HashSet<Long>` to `HashSet<Integer>` and `list.add(n%10)` to `list.add((int) n%10)`.

This gave me the correct answer, 7652413. So, can anyone explain why the contains method works differently for `Long` when compared to `Integer`?

Comment: @pvg I haven't included the entire code because only this method was returning wrongly. I didn't understand `this is almost certainly because your parameter doesn't actually fit in an int and is truncated`, because `Long` isn't giving me the right answer but `Integer` does.

Comment: You can't do this with a Set anyway. You need a count of each digit, and a Set cannot give you that. And of course you don't need a Set at all, just an array of ten integers.

Comment: @EJP I used HashSet to eliminate duplicate digits as we need a PanDigital number where there is no repetition of numbers

Comment: I repeat. You can't count how many times each digit occurs if you use a Set. You don't need to eliminate duplicate digits: you need to *count* them. If you store them in a Set you've already lost the duplicates before you go to count them. Your algorithm doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP  I don't need a count of how many times a digit occurs, if you see my code I'm counting the number of digits using the count variable inside the while loop. PanDigital means it must contain all digits from 1 to n, I'm checking that in my second for loop (This returns false when there is any repetition of numbers). To return false if number contains digits greater than n like 7654319, I wrote the 1st for loop. That's what all I wrote. If you are trying to tell something else please elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`contains(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method doesn't work different for `Long` vs `Integer`. It works exactly the same, i.e.

> Returns `true` if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this set contains an element `e` such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Notice however that method accepts `Object` as parameter type, not `E`. That means you can call it with any type of object. Of course, any object type other than `E` would cause it to return `false`, since `equals()` would fail for objects of different types *(with some exceptions)*.

So, when you call `contains(x)`, and `x` is a *primitive*, it will be auto-boxed, based on the type of `x`, *not* on the type of `E`. So if `x` is an `int` and `E` is `Long`, it'll always return `false`.

It is not `contains()` that suddenly works different, when you change `Long` to `Integer`. It is your code that works different, by correctly matching the type of value passed to `contains()` to the type of elements in the collection.

---

**UPDATE**

Your code is not very efficient:

- It takes a `Long` as a parameter, but max `n` is by nature `9`, and and `int` can store 9-digit numbers without overflow, so use of `Long`, and use of boxing, is unnecessary.
- It allocates a new `HashSet` for every value being checked, and autoboxes every digit found, plus 9 times for the `contains()` calls.

Instead, this can be done using bit-manipulation, since as 32-bit `int` value can easily store 10 boolean values (flags) indicating whether a digit was present.

The code below will establish two bit-masks, `found` and `expected`, which will indicate whether a digit is found, and whether a digit was supposed to be found. Since solution should only use digits 1-n, we'll claim digit 0 is present and expected *(makes logic simpler, not having to do special checks for 0)*.

If a digit is presented twice (or digit 0 is presented once), another expected digit will be missing, and `found` will not equal `expected`.

```
private static boolean isPandigital(int number) {
    int found = 1, expected = 1;
    for (int n = number; n != 0; n /= 10, expected = (expected << 1) | 1)
        found |= 1 << (n % 10);
    return (found == expected);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your explanation. I'm passing integer to `contains()` and the list also contains integers as I'm casting them while they are getting added to the `list`. So, I didn't get your explanation. But thanks for the code. It works pretty fast. I'm a beginner so I couldn't write efficient algorithms.

Comment: @SreevathsaGowru You said that `contains(i)` worked different when it was `HashSet<Long>` and `list.add(n%10)`, vs when it is `HashSet<Integer>` and `list.add((int) n%10)`. That is because `contains(i)` is checking for existence of an `Integer`, which always failed when set elements were `Long`, and works now that set elements are also `Integer`. It is not `contains()` that work different, it is your code that now correctly builds a set of `Integer` elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code run correctly,see your code whose `list` is `HashSet<Long>`:

```
for(int i = 1; i<= count; i++){
    if(!list.contains(i)) return false;
}
```

you can change the type of variable `i` to `long`,or change `if(!list.contains(i)) return false;` to the `if(!list.contains(Long.valueOf(i))) return false;`

Because of the `contains` will check element in existence by the element's method `equals`.In above code,the variable `i` is auto-boxed to `Integer` instance,because the variable `i` is primitive `int`.
And see the Integer `equals`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

but your `list` element's type is `Long`,so the line `if(!list.contains(i)) return false;` will return false always.